# Does spark saveAsTable really create a table?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

This may be a dumb question since lack of some fundamental knowledge of spark, I try this:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("spark ...").master("local").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> df = spark.range(10).toDF();
df.write().saveAsTable("foo");
```

This creates table under 'default' database in Hive, and of course, I can fetch data from the table anytime I want.

I update above code to get rid of "enableHiveSupport",

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("spark ...").master("local").getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> df = spark.range(10).toDF();
df.write().saveAsTable("bar");
```

The code runs fine, without any error, but when I try "select * from bar", spark says,

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException: Table or view 'bar' not found in database 'default';
```

So I have 2 questions here,

1) Is it possible to create a 'raw' spark table, not hive table? I know Hive mantains the metadata in database like mysql, does spark also have similar mechanism?

2) In the 2nd code snippet, what does spark actually create when calling saveAsTable?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check answers below:

1. If you want to create `raw` table only in spark `createOrReplaceTempView` could help you. For second part, check next answer.
2. By default, if you call `saveAsTable` on your dataframe, it will persistent tables into Hive metastore if you use `enableHiveSupport`. And if we don't `enableHiveSupport`, tables will be managed by Spark and data will be under `spark-warehouse` location. You will loose these tables after restart spark session.

Comment: Hi, registerTempTable is deprecated, use createOrReplaceTempView(viewName) instead. But createOrReplaceTempView doesn't help, I mean, like saveAsTable, I cannot fetch data from it in a new session.

Comment: Thank you about your reminder, and if you want to fetch tables from new session we have to use hive support